# Error: NJS-045: cannot load a node-oracledb Thick mode binary for Node.js (Next.js 13.5.3)

Tags: webpack, next.js13, node-oracledb

I created a nextjs v13.5.3 project and installed node-oracledb 6.1.0. When I run the app I get the following error:

```
Critical dependency: require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/oracledb/lib/oracledb.js
./node_modules/oracledb/index.js
./app/api/employees/route.js
 ⨯ node_modules\oracledb\lib\errors.js (588:9) @ getErr
 ⨯ Error: NJS-045: cannot load a node-oracledb Thick mode binary for Node.js. Please try using Thin mode.
  Looked for F:\NextJS\HumanResources\human_resources\.next\server\build\Release\oracledb-6.1.0-win32-x64.node, F:\NextJS\HumanResources\human_resources\.next\server\build\Release\oracledb.node, F:\NextJS\HumanResources\human_resources\.next\server\build\Debug\oracledb.node, F:\NextJS\HumanResources\human_resources\.next\server\vendor-chunks\node_modules\oracledb\build\Release\oracledb-6.1.0-win32-x64.node, F:\NextJS\HumanResources\human_resources\.next\server\vendor-chunks\node_modules\oracledb\build\Release\oracledb.node
  Node-oracledb installation instructions: https://node-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html

    at Object.throwErr (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/oracledb/lib/errors.js:451:11)
    at _initCLib (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/oracledb/lib/oracledb.js:93:24)
    at Object.initOracleClient (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/oracledb/lib/oracledb.js:524:30)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./app/api/employees/route.js:13:10)
    at (rsc)/./app/api/employees/route.js (F:\NextJS\HumanResources\human_resources\.next\server\app\api\employees\route.js:238:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (F:\NextJS\HumanResources\human_resources\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:33:42)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/next-app-loader.js?name=app%2Fapi%2Femployees%2Froute&page=%2Fapi%2Femployees%2Froute&appPaths=&pagePath=private-next-app-dir%2Fapi%2Femployees%2Froute.js&appDir=F%3A%5CNextJS%5CHumanResources%5Chuman_resources%5Capp&pageExtensions=tsx&pageExtensions=ts&pageExtensions=jsx&pageExtensions=js&rootDir=F%3A%5CNextJS%5CHumanResources%5Chuman_resources&isDev=true&tsconfigPath=tsconfig.json&basePath=&assetPrefix=&nextConfigOutput=&preferredRegion=&middlewareConfig=e30%3D!:16:124)
    at (rsc)/./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/next-app-loader.js?name=app%2Fapi%2Femployees%2Froute&page=%2Fapi%2Femployees%2Froute&appPaths=&pagePath=private-next-app-dir%2Fapi%2Femployees%2Froute.js&appDir=F%3A%5CNextJS%5CHumanResources%5Chuman_resources%5Capp&pageExtensions=tsx&pageExtensions=ts&pageExtensions=jsx&pageExtensions=js&rootDir=F%3A%5CNextJS%5CHumanResources%5Chuman_resources&isDev=true&tsconfigPath=tsconfig.json&basePath=&assetPrefix=&nextConfigOutput=&preferredRegion=&middlewareConfig=e30%3D! (F:\NextJS\HumanResources\human_resources\.next\server\app\api\employees\route.js:216:1)   
    at __webpack_require__ (F:\NextJS\HumanResources\human_resources\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:33:42)
    at __webpack_exec__ (F:\NextJS\HumanResources\human_resources\.next\server\app\api\employees\route.js:248:39)
    at F:\NextJS\HumanResources\human_resources\.next\server\app\api\employees\route.js:249:108
    at __webpack_require__.X (F:\NextJS\HumanResources\human_resources\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:163:21)
    at F:\NextJS\HumanResources\human_resources\.next\server\app\api\employees\route.js:249:47
    at Object.<anonymous> (F:\NextJS\HumanResources\human_resources\.next\server\app\api\employees\route.js:252:3)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1241:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1295:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1091:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:938:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1115:19)
    at mod.require (F:\NextJS\HumanResources\human_resources\node_modules\next\dist\server\require-hook.js:64:28)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:130:18)
    at requirePage (F:\NextJS\HumanResources\human_resources\node_modules\next\dist\server\require.js:109:84)
    at F:\NextJS\HumanResources\human_resources\node_modules\next\dist\server\load-components.js:59:84
    at async loadComponentsImpl (F:\NextJS\HumanResources\human_resources\node_modules\next\dist\server\load-components.js:59:26)
    at async DevServer.findPageComponentsImpl (F:\NextJS\HumanResources\human_resources\node_modules\next\dist\server\next-server.js:438:36) {
  code: 'NJS-045',
  page: '/api/employees'
}
null
 ⚠ ./node_modules/oracledb/lib/oracledb.js
Critical dependency: require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/oracledb/lib/oracledb.js
./node_modules/oracledb/index.js
./app/api/employees/route.js
 ⚠ ./node_modules/oracledb/lib/oracledb.js
Critical dependency: require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/oracledb/lib/oracledb.js
./node_modules/oracledb/index.js
./app/api/employees/route.js
 ⚠ ./node_modules/oracledb/lib/oracledb.js
Critical dependency: require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/oracledb/lib/oracledb.js
./node_modules/oracledb/index.js
./app/api/employees/route.js
 ⚠ ./node_modules/oracledb/lib/oracledb.js
Critical dependency: require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/oracledb/lib/oracledb.js
./node_modules/oracledb/index.js
./app/api/employees/route.js
 ⨯ node_modules\oracledb\lib\errors.js (588:9) @ getErr
 ⨯ Error: NJS-045: cannot load a node-oracledb Thick mode binary for Node.js. Please try using Thin mode.
  Looked for F:\NextJS\HumanResources\human_resources\.next\server\build\Release\oracledb-6.1.0-win32-x64.node, F:\NextJS\HumanResources\human_resources\.next\server\build\Release\oracledb.node, F:\NextJS\HumanResources\human_resources\.next\server\build\Debug\oracledb.node, F:\NextJS\HumanResources\human_resources\.next\server\vendor-chunks\node_modules\oracledb\build\Release\oracledb-6.1.0-win32-x64.node, F:\NextJS\HumanResources\human_resources\.next\server\vendor-chunks\node_modules\oracledb\build\Release\oracledb.node
  Node-oracledb installation instructions: https://node-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html

    at Object.throwErr (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/oracledb/lib/errors.js:451:11)
    at _initCLib (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/oracledb/lib/oracledb.js:93:24)
    at Object.initOracleClient (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/oracledb/lib/oracledb.js:524:30)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./app/api/employees/route.js:13:10)
    at (rsc)/./app/api/employees/route.js (F:\NextJS\HumanResources\human_resources\.next\server\app\api\employees\route.js:238:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (F:\NextJS\HumanResources\human_resources\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:33:42)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/next-app-loader.js?name=app%2Fapi%2Femployees%2Froute&page=%2Fapi%2Femployees%2Froute&appPaths=&pagePath=private-next-app-dir%2Fapi%2Femployees%2Froute.js&appDir=F%3A%5CNextJS%5CHumanResources%5Chuman_resources%5Capp&pageExtensions=tsx&pageExtensions=ts&pageExtensions=jsx&pageExtensions=js&rootDir=F%3A%5CNextJS%5CHumanResources%5Chuman_resources&isDev=true&tsconfigPath=tsconfig.json&basePath=&assetPrefix=&nextConfigOutput=&preferredRegion=&middlewareConfig=e30%3D!:16:124)
    at (rsc)/./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/next-app-loader.js?name=app%2Fapi%2Femployees%2Froute&page=%2Fapi%2Femployees%2Froute&appPaths=&pagePath=private-next-app-dir%2Fapi%2Femployees%2Froute.js&appDir=F%3A%5CNextJS%5CHumanResources%5Chuman_resources%5Capp&pageExtensions=tsx&pageExtensions=ts&pageExtensions=jsx&pageExtensions=js&rootDir=F%3A%5CNextJS%5CHumanResources%5Chuman_resources&isDev=true&tsconfigPath=tsconfig.json&basePath=&assetPrefix=&nextConfigOutput=&preferredRegion=&middlewareConfig=e30%3D! (F:\NextJS\HumanResources\human_resources\.next\server\app\api\employees\route.js:216:1)   
    at __webpack_require__ (F:\NextJS\HumanResources\human_resources\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:33:42)
    at __webpack_exec__ (F:\NextJS\HumanResources\human_resources\.next\server\app\api\employees\route.js:248:39)
    at F:\NextJS\HumanResources\human_resources\.next\server\app\api\employees\route.js:249:108
    at __webpack_require__.X (F:\NextJS\HumanResources\human_resources\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:163:21)
    at F:\NextJS\HumanResources\human_resources\.next\server\app\api\employees\route.js:249:47
    at Object.<anonymous> (F:\NextJS\HumanResources\human_resources\.next\server\app\api\employees\route.js:252:3)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1241:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1295:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1091:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:938:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1115:19)
    at mod.require (F:\NextJS\HumanResources\human_resources\node_modules\next\dist\server\require-hook.js:64:28)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:130:18)
    at requirePage (F:\NextJS\HumanResources\human_resources\node_modules\next\dist\server\require.js:109:84)
    at F:\NextJS\HumanResources\human_resources\node_modules\next\dist\server\load-components.js:59:84
    at async loadComponentsImpl (F:\NextJS\HumanResources\human_resources\node_modules\next\dist\server\load-components.js:59:26)
    at async DevServer.findPageComponentsImpl (F:\NextJS\HumanResources\human_resources\node_modules\next\dist\server\next-server.js:438:36) {
  code: 'NJS-045',
  page: '/api/employees'
}
null
 ○ Compiling /_error ...
```

I installed Oracle instant client_21_7 that supports my oracle database 11g and the following are snippets of my code:
./app/test/route.js:

```
const oracledb = require('oracledb');
oracledb.initOracleClient({ libDir: 'C:\\Oracle\\instantclient_12_1' });
```

-package.json:

```
{
  "name": "human_resources",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.js",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "startNow": "webpack --config webpack.config.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "latest",
    "oracledb": "^6.1.0",
    "react": "latest",
    "react-dom": "latest"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "latest",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^11.0.0",
    "postcss": "latest",
    "tailwindcss": "latest",
    "webpack": "^5.88.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "react-countup/countup.js": "2.5.0"
  }
}
```

-webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const {CleanWebpackPlugin} = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

const config = {
  entry: './index.js',
  target: 'node',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'myapp.js',
  },
  mode: 'production',
  watch: false,
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new CopyPlugin({
      patterns: [{
        // Copy Thick-mode Oracle Database driver binaries to dist
        from: path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/oracledb/build'),
        to: 'node_modules/oracledb/build',
      }],
    })
  ],
};

module.exports = config;
```

I still get the same Erorr.

Comment: In my limited experimentation, I was able to use node-oracledb 6 Thin mode but didn't manage to get Thick mode working.  Can you remove the call to `initOracleClient()` and use Thin mode?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with nextjs version > 13, I was able to resolve it by adding the following to my `next.config.js`

```
experimental: {
    serverComponentsExternalPackages: ["oracledb"],
},
```

Currently using versions:

- node 20.2.0
- next 13.5.5
- oracledb 6.2.0

Please note - If you are using thin mode and any version higher than oracledb@5.5.0, you will need

- `sec_case_sensitive_logon` to be `true`
- `password_versions` to not include `10G`

mentioned here https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/issues/1584#issuecomment-1702511642

You should be fine in thick mode

Hope this helps!

Comment: It helps a lot.  Thanks!  An additional note is that code needs to additionally call `oracledb.initOracleClient();`, but this is obvious to users that want Thick mode.